# I need to run some bash from PHP webpage

Tags: php, bash, variables

I have a bash script as below :

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat domains` ; do
tag=$(echo -n $i" -   "; whois $i | grep -o "Expir.*")
reg=$(echo -n -"     "; whois $i | grep "Registrar:")
echo $tag $reg

sleep .5s
done;
```

I wish to have a php page where a user can paste in a list of domains and when they hit send it calls the bash script processes the domains and returns the output. Is this possible?

Comment: The preferred way to iterate over a text file is `while read -r i; do ...; done < domains`. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but you will need to take care when executing a command with user input. You can use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or backticks to execute a command on the server from PHP.

Just take care to make sure that what the user entered is actually a URL and not something meant to execute a malicious command on your server.

---

**Example:**

Your code might look something like this:

```
$output = array();
$urls = $_POST["urls"];
// perform necessary sanitation checks if needed
exec('/path/to/your/script '. implode(' ', $urls), $output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: I am not too fussed about security in the sense that it is a work tool, and only 4 people will have access to it, and they have root on the server anyhow!

Comment: Variable expansions are not rescanned as commands, so the script can't execute a malicious command. However, he you still quote `"$i"` to prevent wildcards from being expanded.

Comment: @Barmar: But he has to execute a command in PHP to call the bash script, and he will have to pass parameters to that bash file. So PHP could execute a malicious command. Right? (This is more for general knowledge, since the OP has indicated that it will be used in a controlled environment).

Comment: I was assuming he was running the above script, which doesn't take any parameters, it just reads from a file. But see my use of `addslashes` in my PHP version of his script.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, I like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

yep you can use `exec()` or `shell_exec()` command

Comment: So I need to look at getting the input to the bash script, how would I do that?

Comment: Take a look at `proc_open`, it allows you to provide pipes for input and output of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to run the bash script? Here's the equivalent PHP code:

```
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
  $domain = addslashes($domain);
  exec("whois '$domain'", $results);
  foreach ($results as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/Expir.*/', $line, $matches)) $tag = $matches[0];
    if (preg_match('/Registrar:/', $line)) $reg = $line;
  }
  echo $domain.' - '.$tag.' - '$reg."\n";
  usleep(500000);
}
```

Comment: +1 - I like this solution better than relying on an external dependency. If that's all the bash script does, this seems like a better way to do it.

Comment: oh i missed a part of the code off**
reg=$(echo -n -"     "; whois $i | grep "Registrar:")
**should be

**reg=$(echo -n -"     "; whois $i | grep  -A1 "Registrar:" | tr -d '\n')**